# Distinct SQLite query-result to Python List or Tuple

Tags: python, sqlite

I have a query that returns e.g. the following result:

```
Row1: "Schmidt"
Row2: "Schmidt, Meier"
Row3: "Mustermann, Schmidt"
```

Question: how do I get the results in a Python tuple or list etc:?
I would like the following list:

```
"Meier, Mustermann, Schmidt".
```

Each name appears only once.

Python code which executes the query (used to populate entries for a comboBox):

class DatabaseManager(object):
    def **init**(self, db):
        self.conn = sqlite3.connect(db)
        self.cur = self.conn.cursor()

```
def get_names(self):
        sSql = "SELECT   DISTINCT name "\
               "  FROM   patient "\
               " ORDER BY 1"
        return self.cur.execute(sSql)
```

And this is called from an instance which populates the results into a comboBox:

```
def populate_names(self, combobox):
        rows = self.db.get_names()
        for row in rows:
            combobox.addItem(row[0])
```

Comment: What Python code are you using to execute the query?

Comment: Your expected outcome is a string, not a list, and how did it get that ordering?

Comment: DISTINCT because entries may repeat, e.g. to extend the example from above:
Row4: "Mustermann, Schmidt"
Row5: "Schmidt"

Comment: I want to have the distinct entries in a combobox.

Comment: @ScottHunter: added the cody to my original posting.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create an empty list to hold the names.

Loop through each name in the query result.

If the current name is not already in the list, add it.

Something like this:

```
names = []
for row in sql_result:
    if row['name'] not in names:
        names.append(row['name'])
```

Comment: Why use a list and not a set?

Comment: Because he said "I would like the following list".

Comment: But you're creating a brand new list and doing a membership of your collection with `if row['name'] not in names`; there's no reason for O(N) lookup. Just convert it back to a list at the end

Comment: Actually, the output is a single string so I don't think the OP has explained the problem properly